# Auth0 login endpoint not working after following tutorial

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

I followed the introduction tutorial on implementing auth0 with nodejs and express.

This is my following code:

```
const { auth } = require('express-openid-connect');
const express = require('express');
const config = {
    authRequired: false,
    auth0Logout: true,
    secret: 'secret',
    baseURL: 'https://3803-188-124-153-232.ngrok.io',
    clientID: '',
    issuerBaseURL: ''
};
const app = express();

// auth router attaches /login, /logout, and /callback routes to the baseURL
app.use(auth(config));

// req.isAuthenticated is provided from the auth router
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.oidc.isAuthenticated());
    res.send("hello");
});

app.listen(3000)
```

I first tried to use localhost:3000, and thought that might be the issue for callbacks and the login endpoint. Therefore, i tried using ngrok to forward to localhost:3000 as well. Both of my attempts did not work.

This is the error i receive when visiting the login endpoint:

```
AggregateError: Issuer.discover() failed.
    OPError: expected 200 OK with body but no body was returned
    OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 404 Not Found
```

I have no idea why I receive this error or how to fix it. Any help would be nice. I have triple checked that the baseURL, clientID and issuerBaseURL are correct.